# Android mapping async downloaded image to listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-asynctask

I have a ListView that each item in the list contains multiple images.

When I create the list, I want to async download the image so the list can show fast and the images can fill in when they are downloaded.

I have extended the `AsyncTask` class and implemented a simple download method. However, I am not sure how to update the image back to the correct position in the list view in:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    // TODO show the downloaded image to the list

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Here's my class definition:

```
public class ImageDownloadWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
```

And my `doInBackground` method:

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

What is the common pattern we should use to map the downloaded image to the correct ImageView of the correct list item in the list? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an adapter pattern to populate the listview. In your case, you can create a custom adapter class and extend BaseAdapter and implement all its methods. The pattern goes like this.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }

    private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
              return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
               return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(bitmap);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        }
    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
        }

        public CustomAdapter(Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                holder.image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.image.setImageBitmap();

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, when you are loading many images into the listview, create an ArrayList and send that to the listAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I need to do the same of you in lot of projects and this library is very very helpful and very simple to use:

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper